# Как перекинуть проект c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть проект c#, к меня на пк все запускается через exe, все нормально, перекидываю на гугл диск, на остальных пк не работает, запускается консоль и сразу же пропадает, моментально, даже console.readline(); не помогает, хотя у меня он работает,. Я мельком успел увидеть, там написано failing .... В чем ошибка? Как нормально перекинуть.

Еще вот: Есть проект на c#, в нем есть екзешник, на моем пк все работает, на других, запускается на долю секунды и все, я мельком глаза увидел fataling...., Это консольное приложение, странно, что на моем все работает, на других, нет. Может ч как-то не так переношу проект. Еще заметил, если перекидываю на Гугл диск, маил облако, то добавляется еще одна папка .vs, хотя у меня её нету

Comment: А сторонние длл не подключаете в коде?

Comment: посмотрите полное сообщение об ошибке, возможно понятнее будет

Comment: Возможно нет .NET Framework'a подходящей версии.

Comment: Ну если на пк вообще нету visual studio и тп, это может влиять?

Comment: .net framework это для запуска exeшников от c# и тп? Если это так, то вы решили мою проблеммв, т.к на этих пк не было ничего связанного с visual studio .net c# и та

Comment: @PrinceTag с вижуалкой ставится фраемворк, может быть его у вас нет, раз нет и вижуалки. И еще, для запуска на другом компьютере обычно используются Release сборки .exe. Попробуйте собрать такую и запустить на компе без вижуалки.

Comment: Да, @HideME прав и вашу проблему можно решить двумя способами: собрать под ту версию фреймворка, которая стоит на машинах с виндой по умолчанию (для этого понизьте версию в проекте и перекомпилируйте), либо посмотрите под какой фреймворк заточен проект и на компах ставьте такой же.

Comment: Запустите обычную CMD, там пропишите полный путь до файла (`C:\MyFile.exe`) и посмотрите что вам выдаст консоль. Без логов тут только гадать..

Comment: Запустил, пишет:
A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found. 
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [C:\Users\13vac\Desktop\Tzx\Tzx\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\]. 
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [C:\Program Files\dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation].

Comment: The .NET Core runtime can be found at: 
 - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
[Ссылка]
Download .NET (Linux, macOS, and Windows)
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&amp;arch=x64&amp;rid=win10-x64

Comment: Ну вот и ваша проблема `The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.`

Comment: Я так понял, что нету на пк .net, так?

Comment: Почему она не работает на этих пк, на моем все нормально, я же скопировал и перекинул, как так?

Comment: У вас проект .net core? Если да, то установлен ли он на других устройствах? Судя по тому, что вам в ошибке еще и ссылку дают, то думаю, что нет.

Comment: Почитайте раздел `Однофайловые исполняемые файлы` [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0)

Comment: Да, нет кор, походу он не установлен, в этом и ошибка, спасибо за разъяснения

Comment: [Развертывание приложений .NET Core с помощью Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156)